# How to fix the Image inside CircleAvatar when the window is being resized in flutter web

Tags: flutter

[image]
[image]

The thing is I want the image to be fixed even when the window is being resized , Here's the code :

```
CircleAvatar(
     radius: 60.0,
     backgroundImage: const AssetImage('images/profile.png'),
     ),
```

I tried using SizedBox , FittedBox Align Center and nothing actually worked , I wondering if is it even possible to make it fix in a place

Comment: but i think this working fine.

Comment: Check out the Dog image in both of the above outputs , in second output the image is being zoomed in

Answer (score 1):

**Try `Align` Widget Like This:**

```
  Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,//aligns CircleAvatar to Top Center.
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 50,//radius is 50
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/03/20/42/man-657869_1280.jpg'),
                  ),
                ),
```

Read This [Documentation](https://androidride.com/flutter-circle-avatar-widget/) 
See This

[Image 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PTe_4qV_fJo5rCAU5VT10XrLr3aMVbwB/view?usp=share_link) And [Image2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t4is4pgd6JwH1Ydi31-TM23qs724jwR7/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: umm , in ur code it says ```Alignment.topCenter``` , but in the image it is aligned at ```topLeft``` .

Comment: your question is that how to fix the Image inside CircleAvatar when the window is being resized in flutter web ?? In My Example code i will just share and idea

Comment: Ya i get it , don't take it any other way mate and again appreciate it for taking the time to answer !!

Answer (score 0):

change the radius of circle avatar according to screen width using media query like this.

```
CircleAvatar(
     radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
     backgroundImage: const AssetImage('images/profile.png'),
     ),
```

change 0.4 to any value want

Comment: ummm ,thanks for responding , however i was using `MaterialApp` widget so this didn't actually work for me . I fixed it this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/75600739/19810067

Answer (score 0):

you may use use [nb_utils][1] package to create responsive apps, To make responsive avatar you can use radius 40.w. so 40.w will be responsive according to width of screen.
initialize nb_utils in main.dart file for initializing.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await initialize();

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Supported Platform

1. Android
2. Ios
3. Windows
4. Web
5. Linux
6. macos

> ```
> CircleAvatar(
>              radius: 40.w,
>              backgroundImage: const AssetImage('images/profile.png'),
>              ),
> ```

you may change 40.w according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by removing the `BackgroundImage` and also cropping the image into circular instead of default rectangle (I named it as "profile-modified"). I used `Image.assest` as a child of `CircleAvatar` and using `fit: BoxFit.cover` .

The modified code looks this way :

```
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 60.0,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'images/profile-modified.png',
                     fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
```